# git doesn't respond to neither 'git push' nor 'git pull' commands, no error messages

Tags: git, github, push, bitbucket, message

I have faced and now completely stocked in a quite unpleasant situation, where git doesn't want to collaborate with me in any way.

Initially, I was working in detached/head mode and made some changes. Then I decided to create a new branch (branch is from detached state) and switched over to it. Then I made a couple more changes along with commits. After that I, finally, merged new branch with my initial local branch called 'develop', to be able to push all my work on server.

All operation were accomplished without any issues or problems. No error messages received. However, as soon as I start trying to push changes using:

```
git push origin develop
```

I receive no response at all. I have checked my `git config --list`, it seems to be fine.

I really need someone's advice to start solving the problem, because it's crucial for me. The main problem is that I don't understand the root of a problem, so I hope to find any hint to the solution here. I have read a lot of info about similar cases, however, no appropriate answers were found.

Comment: What does "no response at all" mean? Does the command hang? Does the command complete without any output? Something else?

Comment: Try using `GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin develop`, you might want to paste output here.

Comment: Chris, when I say 'no response at all' I imply, that the command doesn't hang, it just switches to the next line in terminal:
debian% git push origin develop   -  the command I type,
debian%  - and then empty line appears for entering other commands

Comment: @Abhijeet Kasurde, After typing in command given above I received next output: debian% GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin develop 16:01:53.755572 git.c:350 trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'develop' 16:01:53.759259 run-command.c:336 trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'Nick_Ozhoh@....git'; Frankly saying, yet, I can't understand how this can help me.

Comment: By the way, guys, don't you think it can be an issues caused by git itself? The point is that when I made my last 'git push' command I probably used previous git version, because after a couple of days I made system upgrade, and I think git package had been updated as well. As for now I have git version 2.10.1 and consider downgrade as an option, because I see no other ways. What you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the situation what you said. But be sure, before you push the changes to remote repo, remember to commit the changes.

Comment: thank you, but a couple of commits have been made. 'git status' says, that my branch 'develop' is ahead by 2 commits of my 'origin/develop', which means that I should be able to perform 'git push', however, I still can't

Comment: @Nick have you found any clue about that?